# WP Fastest Cache -> Render Blocking Js -> Exclude Js Sources

Tags: plugins

I want to exclude js aources as shown on [https://www.wpfastestcache.com/premium/render-blocking-js/ .

The info ont thebottom of the site shows "you need to add `data-wpfc-render="false"` attribute."

So it looks like this

```
<script data-wpfc-render="false" src="http://www.x/xyz.js"></script>
```

I need to add this attribute to 2 scripts from a plugin, wich are inside the ("head" part of the) loaded wordpress site.

How can i do this? How can i "tell the site" to add the attribute to the specific script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`script_loader_tag` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) to accomplish this. This hook passes in the tag HTML that you can search on, then add in your data attribute.

```
/**
 * Modify script tags as they're loaded
 *
 * @param String $tag_html
 *
 * @return String $tag_html
 */
function wpse379555_script_tag( $tag_html ) {

    if( false === strpos( $tag_html, 'wpfastestcache' ) ) {
        return $tag_html;
    }

    return str_replace( ' src=', ' data-wpfc-render="false" src=', $tag_html );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse379555_script_tag' );
```